# Delay function without using a timer

Tags: time

Is there a delay function available that does not use `millis()` which itself makes use of a timer? Does not need to be hyper-exact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delayMicroseconds(1000);// maximum delay is 65535 uS
```

or

```
#include <util/delay.h>
_delay_ms(1);
```

Comment: `delayMicroseconds()` does not accept `long int` (32-bits) but only `unsigned int` (16-bits), hence the maximum you can pass it is `65535`.